# Travel with a passport and a US travel document

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel

I've been living in the USA for 1 year but I'm not a citizen and I don't have a USA passport, I just have a Travel document. It means I can come back to the USA again, also I have my own country's passport. I can't enter my country with the US travel document.

I want to leave the USA with that travel document and show it when entering Turkey. From there I will travel to another country with another passport. Is it possible? This passport doesn't have the entry stamp.

After a few days I will be back in Turkey with same passport that I used to leave Turkey and with travel document will move to the USA.

Comment: The US travel document is not enough to enter this third country or do you actually need to hide the fact you have one? The former is not a big problem (you can always show two travel documents if there are any question), the latter is more difficult as the lack of Turkish stamp will in that case be a problem. Also, when you say “another country”, is that the country from which you also have a passport?

Comment: it would help if you would name the countries involved. I don't expect a US travel document would get you into any country except the USA. Therefore this seems to be "will my passport get me into Turkey?" and I don't see why it's a question. Also, just how many passports are involved here?

Comment: @KateGregory Apparently, [some countries do accept it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Re-entry_Permit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it should not be a problem (see [Travelling with two different passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/travelling-with-two-different-passports?rq=1)). Show the US travel document to the airline when starting the trip back to the US (to prove that you will be able to enter the US and make sure the right document is submitted to the US authorities) and otherwise use whatever document you need to use when crossing a boarder.

Thus when leaving Turkey, if asked by the Turkish border guards, show them the document you used to enter Turkey. The border guards in the country you will enter next probably don't care about any entry/exit stamps from Turkey but if they do you can still show them both your other passport and the document with the Turkish stamps. In most countries, this should be enough to clarify any issue and reasonable requests (e.g. to stamp one passport or the other) will typically be honored.

The only real problem is if you need to hide one of them for some reason (e.g. you are going to a country that makes trouble for people who visited some other country, you want to make sure the US authorities don't know you have been to this unnamed third country, or you want to hide the fact that you have a US re-entry permit). In that case, any discrepancy between the stamps (a dangling exit stamp without entry elsewhere, showing up at a border checkpoint without exit stamp from the country you just left, etc.) could raise questions. Worse case, your luggage could even get searched and the document you wished to hide could be found. It's always risky to try to hide something at a border. But otherwise there is no reason why using several passports should be a problem.

Comment: +1 but unclear if Turkish officials will allow someone presenting only a US Reentry Permit to enter Turkey.  It would put them at odds with border controls they are *SUPPOSED* to be implementing for the EEA application.