# Dual Citizenship (Guyana and UK) and obtaining a US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, guyanese-citizens

I am a dual citizen with 2 passports. Passport 1 is from my birth country, Guyana, and passport 2 is from the UK. The Guyanese government has the option of stripping your Guyanese citizenship if they know you use another citizenship, so I would like them not to know. If, for example, you have a US visa in passport 2 (departing from birth country) and like to travel to the US, how would you proceed?

Possible solution is to go to the US embassy (in birth country) and reapply for a new visa on passport 1 but wouldn’t they question why you’re doing that since the other one is still valid? Plus there are many questions on the form to fill out regarding that. They will obviously see that you also have a citizenship not belonging to the country you’re in so will they report it? Or do you just wait till it expires before applying with another passport?

Since there's no direct flight to destination, stopover country is visa free for both passports.

Comment: It'd be really useful if you could tell us which the countries are.

Comment: Guyana is the birth country.

Comment: ...and the other one?

Comment: The other one is British.

Answer (score 6):

**Easy**, just use both passports, as [explained in detail here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/travelling-with-two-different-passports):

1. Book your flights with details per passport 2.
2. At check-in, show passport 2 to prove you can enter the US.
3. At exit immigration, show passport 1.
4. When entering the US, show passport 2.
5. When checking in for return flight, show passport 2.  If asked for visa to country 1, show passport 1.
6. At entry immigration, show passport 1.

The **main catch** is that, if country 1 *really* cares about you not having multiple citizenships (can you tell us which country it is?), immigration officers may look for visas for/stamps from the US and start asking awkward questions if they can't find any.  The usual ploy around this is to swap passports at a connection point: for example, dual Malaysian/Australian citizens usually travel via Singapore, so Malaysia thinks they're visiting Singapore only (no visa needed).

Comment: The country I'm referring to is Guyana. 
Isn't it better to just buy two roundtrip tickets (although that may get pricey)? (Guyana-stopover country  // stopover country-US)

Obviously, two US visas aren't allowed so when I reapply through passport 1, will the embassy automatically cancel the one in passport 2? 

Also, won't check-in check for stamps on when I entered the country? (It won't have any)

Comment: Yes, two completely separate tickets is better.  The airline does not care about your status in the country you're in, they care about whether you'll be allowed into your destination.  And I still don't understand why you think you need two US visas...?

Comment: It's basically to avoid having to go through all the hassle and just travel with one passport.

Comment: Applying for a US visa is much more hassle than carrying two passports.  Also, if you're a British passport holder, you shouldn't need a visa for short tourism or business visits to the US?

Comment: Yes, but pulling that passport out locally isn't something I'm willing to do especially when dual citizenship isn't recognized. So, I'm just trying to find alternatives for having to buy two separate tickets

Comment: Would the US embassy care if you have dual citizenship in a country that doesn't recognize it?

Comment: No, it's quite literally none of their business.  The US allows dual citizenship, end of story.

Comment: @Shawn: There is no such thing as "recognizing" dual nationality. Who has each nationality is determined by that country's laws. If multiple countries' laws say you have their respective nationalities, then you have multiple nationality. There is nothing to "recognize". There is only a question of whether you really have a particular nationality or not.

Comment: @user102008 Is there a point to your pedantry?  The OP's fear is that, if Guyana finds out OP is a British citizen, they'll strip his Guyanese citizenship, which they *are* entitled to do.

Comment: @Shawn The government of Guyana may care, but the airline really does not. They only want to ensure that you'll be allowed into your destination country, as they can get stuck with the bill if you are denied entry to a country and returned to where you came from.

Answer (score 1):

Use your UK passport.

UK/USA "special relationship" means that UK is part of the Visa Waiver Program. Select countries thus don't need visas,since the USA deems them less risky.

Guyana would require a visa for entry.

When applying, you would have to state you have dual nationality, but then this shouldn't be an issue for the US border control. You should ensure though you do enter with your UK passport, possibly even show your Guyanese passport on entry too.