# Transit through the US with two different passports

Tags: usa, transit

I am travelling from Chile to Hong Kong, with a short lay over in USA. I do not have USA visa but hold a Spanish Passport, that I can use to enter the US. However, my visa for entering China, where I will go to after Hong Kong, is on my Chilean passport. Will I have trouble when entering and exiting USA using my Spanish passport?

Answer (score 3):

Nationals of both Spain and Chile can enter and stay in Hong Kong for up to 90 days without a visa. Flying directly to China should be possible as well but in this case, it's not even relevant, you can just present your Spanish passport everywhere in the US (airline counter, border check on entry) and not worry about it. Your visa for China (and therefore your Chilean passport) will only become relevant later when entering Hong Kong and/or China proper.

Another option is to use your Chilean passport for everything, as it is also eligible for the [Visa Waiver Program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html). Only drawback is that you might have to pay a few dollars to get a new ESTA for that passport (if you already have a valid one for your Spanish passport). I don't know whether that's actually mandatory in Chile but it's definitely a good idea to show that passport for the exit immigration check (if there is one in Chile, which I don't know either).

In any case, whatever passport you use for the US part of the trip, the airline has no reason to deny you boarding on a Hong Kong-bound flight, even if you did not have a Chinese visa (which you can however always show them, even as you are using your other passport, see [Travelling with two different passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/travelling-with-two-different-passports)).